# Create a vector layer in Coordinate Reference System USER:10001

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgsvectorlayer

I want to create a vector layer in the this CRS : USER:100001 but i doesn't work. It always tells me, i need to choose the CRS by myself.

> vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=user:100001", "Project_center", "memory")

But when i try it with ESPG:4326, it works as expected.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that the crs USER:100001 already exists? What QGIS-version?

Comment: Yes, it is. QGIS 2.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code `vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=user:100001", "Project_center", "memory")` only works  from QGIS3.0.
For 2.xx you can test the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings

# save actualy value
crsType = QSettings().value('/Projections/defaultBehaviour') # only 2.x

QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehaviour','')
target_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
target_crs.createFromId(100001, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.InternalCrsId)

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "Project_center", "memory")
vl.setCrs(target_crs)
print vl.crs().authid()

# set saved  value
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehaviour',crsType)
```